# Python: Know the second wednesday of the next month with a given date

Tags: python, calendar, date

I would like to know this:

I have for example this date:

```
2011-08-10 wednesday
```

and i would like to know the next second wednesday of the next month:
The answer should be `2011-09-14 wednesday`.

Comment: This is starting to feel like homework

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the comments it was explained that the OP is looking for a function which maps

1. 2011-08-25 (the fourth Thursday) to 2011-09-22 (the fourth Thursday
   of the next  month) and
2. 2011-08-30 (the fifth Tuesday) to 2011-09-27 (the fourth Tuesday,
   because there is no fifth Tuesday in September.)

---

Using [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil):

```
import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta as relativedelta

def next_month(date):
    weekday=relativedelta.weekday(date.isoweekday()-1)   
    weeknum=(date.day-1)//7+1
    weeknum=weeknum if weeknum<=4 else 4
    next_date=date+relativedelta.relativedelta(
        months=1,day=1,weekday=weekday(weeknum))
    return next_date

start=datetime.date(2011,8,1)
for i in range(31):
    date=start+datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    next_date=next_month(date)    
    print('{d} --> {n}'.format(d=date,n=next_date))
```

yields

```
2011-08-01 --> 2011-09-05
2011-08-02 --> 2011-09-06
2011-08-03 --> 2011-09-07
2011-08-04 --> 2011-09-01
2011-08-05 --> 2011-09-02
2011-08-06 --> 2011-09-03
2011-08-07 --> 2011-09-04
2011-08-08 --> 2011-09-12
2011-08-09 --> 2011-09-13
2011-08-10 --> 2011-09-14
2011-08-11 --> 2011-09-08
2011-08-12 --> 2011-09-09
2011-08-13 --> 2011-09-10
2011-08-14 --> 2011-09-11
2011-08-15 --> 2011-09-19
2011-08-16 --> 2011-09-20
2011-08-17 --> 2011-09-21
2011-08-18 --> 2011-09-15
2011-08-19 --> 2011-09-16
2011-08-20 --> 2011-09-17
2011-08-21 --> 2011-09-18
2011-08-22 --> 2011-09-26
2011-08-23 --> 2011-09-27
2011-08-24 --> 2011-09-28
2011-08-25 --> 2011-09-22 # Oddly non-monotonic, but correct according to specifications
2011-08-26 --> 2011-09-23
2011-08-27 --> 2011-09-24
2011-08-28 --> 2011-09-25
2011-08-29 --> 2011-09-26 # 5th Monday maps to 4th Monday since there is no 5th Monday in September
2011-08-30 --> 2011-09-27
2011-08-31 --> 2011-09-28
```

Comment: by given a date.. how do you know how it is the first, second, third, gorth weekday of the month?

Comment: Is that another part to your question? This feels like homework.

Comment: I like this solution, I just don't know how to get the relativedelta attributes for the weekday.. in this example: WE(2)

Comment: @unutbu Your **next_month()** function does partly the same as my  lines: ``yp,mp = (int(y)+1, 1) if m=='12' else (int(y), int(m)+1)`` and ``next_month = ('%s-%s-%s' % (yp,mp,dp) for dp in xrange(1,32))`` . The other part is doing what I do with the number ``n = (int(d)-1)//7`` which is the ordinal numbering the input day. I deducted the next mont 'yp_mp' from the month 'y-m'  of the input date like that because I was embarassed by the fact that **datetime.timedelta()** doesn't have a parameter _months_. I suppose that it's for the same reason that you use **relativedelta())** of **dateutil**.

Comment: @unutbu Personally, I think that resorting to extensions often requires additional effort to learn a great amount of them before being able to use the little part that is desired, while achieving the same processes with the tools already present in Python would be easier and faster. Presently, in your code I remark that you preliminary execute ``date=start+datetime.timedelta(days=i)`` and then in the function, a similar operation ``weekday=relativedelta.weekday(date.isoweekday()-1)`` , for each day you want to obtain in the next month.

Comment: @unutbu  I'm not convinced that dateutil is really indispensable and justified, as much tricky as it may be. - By the way, the start of your code is a ``date`` instance , created from a collection of integers , but the input data in the question is a date under the form of a string. So, to execute your code on strings, there must be preliminary treatments  in addition

Comment: @eyquem: You've stated so many things .. I just can't respond to them all. But I do prefer to use well written modules rather than reinventing wheels. By doing so I get to benefit from the hard work of smart people who have invested much time in testing and improving their code. PS. dateutil was not hard to learn at all, quite fun really :)

Comment: @unutbu I find the 'reinventing the wheel 'argument specious. But I studied more dateutil and it appears very well done and powerful to me. So I think you are right concerning this particular extension, it must be a really useful and easy extension when someone needs to perform complex operations involving time. Some day, I will study it more thoroughly. I simply had already a lot of stir of my brain to learn the **time** and **datetime** modules, hence a tired reaction concerning the learning of **dateutil**

Comment: @unutbu I am just astounded by the existence of billions of applications and extensions , provoking the feeling to be lost in front of this ocean, and indecision, while there are many of them that do the same things, and I also think that resorting to an over-powered extension relatively to simple needs leads to a loose of productivity and simplicity.

Comment: @unutbu Eh, what do you think of my second edit of my answer ? Isn't it simple, clear and readable ? Another problem in resorting to extensions quasi automatically is that one takes the habit to think about less, and to not find simple solutions that need nothing else than tools already present in Python. The potential risk is a lack of skill in the using of these tools

Comment: @eyquem: Everyone is entitled to their own opinion and people's opinions are notoriously hard to change (including my own!). So I don't relish long discussions of opinions and this is all I'm going to say on this matter.

Comment: Let's think about `xdate + timedelta(weeks=min(n,3))`. In a year, will you remember why this code is correct? Or will you have to rewrap your mind around the problem and rethink, step-by-step, why the calculation works? Using `dateutil` is better because it allows one to express the **intention** of the code without getting bogged down in how the calculation is performed. There are many advantages to programming like this: It improves readability, maintainability, the correctness of the code, potential for rapid code development.

Comment: @unutbu You're right but 1) My code is commented : _"There is no couple of adjacent months in a year...."_

Comment: @unutbu 2) It's the same in your code: in a year, will you remember why ``weeknum=weeknum if weeknum<=4 else 4`` ? By the way, this name **weeknum** isn't well fitted to its purpose; it's not the number of a week (Monday to Sunday) but the number of the group of 7 days , among the following ones "days 1 to 7", "days 8 to 14", "days 15 to 21", "days 22 to 28", "days 29 to end of month" , that comprises the input date. That's very difficult to express, and the reason of (date.day-1)//7+1 in your code and (d-1)//7 in mine are also not immediately evident

Answer (score 1):

Why do you explicit need the second wednesday?
It would be more valuable if you knew the weekday position in the month

Comment: The example i put in the question was just an example. I would like to know for the entire month for example, 2011-08-25 is the fourth thursday an the answer of is 2011-08-22 , or for example i have 2011-08.30 that is the fifth Tuesday of the month and the answer should be 2011-09-27 which is the fourth tuesday. because there is no fifth tuesday in setptember

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import *
import re
from sys import exit


dico = {'Monday':0,'monday':0,'Tuesday':1,'tuesday':1,
        'Wednesday':2,'wednesday':2,'Thursday':3,'thursday':3,
        'Friday':4,'friday':4,'Saturday':5,'saturday':5,
        'Sunday':6,'sunday':6}

regx = re.compile('((\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d))\s+(%s)' % '|'.join(dico.iterkeys()))



for s in ('2011-08-10  Wednesday', '2011-08-25    Thursday', '2011-08-30  Tuesday',
          '2011-12-04 Sunday', '2011-12-30   Friday',
          '2012-02-18 Saturday', '2012-02-25 Saturday', '2012-02-29   Wednesday '):

    print 's == ' + s

    try:
        the_date,y,m,d,day_name = regx.match(s).groups()
        wday = dico[day_name]
    except:
        mess = "The string isn't expressing a date correctly"
        exit(mess)

    try:
        s_strp = strptime(the_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    except:
        mess = "The date isn't an existing date"
        exit(mess)

    if s_strp.tm_wday != wday:
        mess = 'The name of week-day in the string is incoherent with the date'
        exit(mess)

    n = (int(d)-1)//7
    print '(y,m,d,day_name,wday,n) ==',(y,m,d,day_name,wday,n)
    print 'The day %s is the %sth %s in the month %s\n' % (d,n+1,day_name,y+'-'+m)


    yp,mp = (int(y)+1, 1) if m=='12' else (int(y), int(m)+1)
    next_month = ('%s-%s-%s' % (yp,mp,dp) for dp in xrange(1,32))
    same_days = []
    for day in next_month:
        try:
            if strptime(day,'%Y-%m-%d').tm_wday==wday:  same_days.append(day)
        except:
            break
    print '%s days in the next month are :\n%s' % (day_name,same_days)
    try:
        print 'The %sth %s in the next month is on date %s' % (n+1,day_name,same_days[n])
    except:
        print 'The last %s (%sth) in the next month is on date %s' % (day_name,n,same_days[n-1])
    print '\n-------------------------------------------------------------'
```

result

```
s == 2011-08-10  Wednesday
(y,m,d,day_name,wday,n) == ('2011', '08', '10', 'Wednesday', 2, 1)
The day 10 is the 2th Wednesday in the month 2011-08

Wednesday days in the next month are :
['2011-9-7', '2011-9-14', '2011-9-21', '2011-9-28']
The 2th Wednesday in the next month is on date 2011-9-14

-------------------------------------------------------------
s == 2011-08-25    Thursday
(y,m,d,day_name,wday,n) == ('2011', '08', '25', 'Thursday', 3, 3)
The day 25 is the 4th Thursday in the month 2011-08

Thursday days in the next month are :
['2011-9-1', '2011-9-8', '2011-9-15', '2011-9-22', '2011-9-29']
The 4th Thursday in the next month is on date 2011-9-22

-------------------------------------------------------------
s == 2011-08-30  Tuesday
(y,m,d,day_name,wday,n) == ('2011', '08', '30', 'Tuesday', 1, 4)
The day 30 is the 5th Tuesday in the month 2011-08

Tuesday days in the next month are :
['2011-9-6', '2011-9-13', '2011-9-20', '2011-9-27']
The last Tuesday (4th) in the next month is on date 2011-9-27

-------------------------------------------------------------
s == 2011-12-04 Sunday
(y,m,d,day_name,wday,n) == ('2011', '12', '04', 'Sunday', 6, 0)
The day 04 is the 1th Sunday in the month 2011-12

Sunday days in the next month are :
['2012-1-1', '2012-1-8', '2012-1-15', '2012-1-22', '2012-1-29']
The 1th Sunday in the next month is on date 2012-1-1

-------------------------------------------------------------
s == 2011-12-30   Friday
(y,m,d,day_name,wday,n) == ('2011', '12', '30', 'Friday', 4, 4)
The day 30 is the 5th Friday in the month 2011-12

Friday days in the next month are :
['2012-1-6', '2012-1-13', '2012-1-20', '2012-1-27']
The last Friday (4th) in the next month is on date 2012-1-27

-------------------------------------------------------------
s == 2012-02-18 Saturday
(y,m,d,day_name,wday,n) == ('2012', '02', '18', 'Saturday', 5, 2)
The day 18 is the 3th Saturday in the month 2012-02

Saturday days in the next month are :
['2012-3-3', '2012-3-10', '2012-3-17', '2012-3-24', '2012-3-31']
The 3th Saturday in the next month is on date 2012-3-17

-------------------------------------------------------------
s == 2012-02-25 Saturday
(y,m,d,day_name,wday,n) == ('2012', '02', '25', 'Saturday', 5, 3)
The day 25 is the 4th Saturday in the month 2012-02

Saturday days in the next month are :
['2012-3-3', '2012-3-10', '2012-3-17', '2012-3-24', '2012-3-31']
The 4th Saturday in the next month is on date 2012-3-24

-------------------------------------------------------------
s == 2012-02-29   Wednesday 
(y,m,d,day_name,wday,n) == ('2012', '02', '29', 'Wednesday', 2, 4)
The day 29 is the 5th Wednesday in the month 2012-02

Wednesday days in the next month are :
['2012-3-7', '2012-3-14', '2012-3-21', '2012-3-28']
The last Wednesday (4th) in the next month is on date 2012-3-28

-------------------------------------------------------------
```

With the string **'2011-08-11 Monday'** the result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\wednesday.py", line 37, in <module>
    exit(mess)
SystemExit: The name of week-day in the string is incoherent with the date
```

With the string **'2011-34-58  Monday'**, error is produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\wednesday.py", line 33, in <module>
    exit(mess)
SystemExit: The date isn't an existing date
```

### Edit 1

I was unsatisfied of my code: it has poor readability
The following one is more understandable

Note that in this new code, **N** hasn't the same meaning as the **n** in the former code

```
from time import strptime
import re
from sys import exit
from datetime import date,timedelta


dico = {'Monday':0,'monday':0,'Tuesday':1,'tuesday':1,
        'Wednesday':2,'wednesday':2,'Thursday':3,'thursday':3,
        'Friday':4,'friday':4,'Saturday':5,'saturday':5,
        'Sunday':6,'sunday':6}

regx = re.compile('((\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d))\s+(%s)' % '|'.join(dico.iterkeys()))



for s in ('2011-08-10  Wednesday', '2011-08-25    Thursday', '2011-08-30  Tuesday',
          '2011-12-04 Sunday', '2011-12-30   Friday',
          '2012-02-18 Saturday', '2012-02-25 Saturday', '2012-02-29   Wednesday ',
          '2011-07-24 sunday', '2011-07-25 monday',
          '2011-10-28 friday', '2011-10-30 monday'):

    print 's == ' + s

    # Verifications ----------------------------------------------------------------
    try:
        the_date,y,m,d,day_name = regx.match(s).groups()
        wday = dico[day_name]
    except:
        mess = "The string isn't expressing a date correctly"
        exit(mess)
    else:
        try:
            s_strp = strptime(the_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
        except:
            mess = "The date isn't an existing date"
            exit(mess)
        else:
            if s_strp.tm_wday != wday:
                mess = 'The name of week-day in the string is incoherent with the date'
                exit(mess)

    # Extraction of needed info -----------------------------------------------------
    y,m,d = map(int,(y,m,d))  # y,m,d = year,month,day
    N = (d-1)//7 + 1  # N is in (1,2,3,4,5) , it tells if the week-day is the first/2nd/3nd/4th/5th in the month 
    print '(y,m,d,day_name,wday,N) ==',(y,m,d,day_name,wday,N)
    print 'The day %s is the %sth %s in the month %s-%s\n' % (d,N,day_name,y,m)

    # Finding the desired next date ------------------------------------------------- 
    ahead = (date(y,m,d) + timedelta(weeks=i) for i in (1,2,3,4,5))
    # this generator yields the 5 next dates of same week-day name after the date 'y-m-d' because the date 'y-m-d'
    # and the date of same week-day name and same position in the next month can't be separated by more than 5 weeks

    cnt = 0
    for xd in ahead:
        cnt += (xd.month != m) # cnt is incremented only if xd is a same week-day in the next month
        if cnt in (N,4):
            # There is no couple of adjacent months in a year
            # having a given week-day name present 5 times in each of them
            # Then if N==5, cnt can't be 5
            print 'The %sth %s %s in the next month is on date %s' % (cnt,day_name,'(the last)' if N==5 else '',xd)
            break
    print '\n-------------------------------------------------------------'
```

### Edit 2

Aaaaaaaaah ! I was having the feeling that the result could be found in very few lines  and I finally got it.
No need of dateutil, no need of my complicated preceding solutions, the following code does the job in 4 lines !

```
import re
from sys import exit
from datetime import date,timedelta
from time import strptime


dico = {'Monday':0,'monday':0,'Tuesday':1,'tuesday':1,
        'Wednesday':2,'wednesday':2,'Thursday':3,'thursday':3,
        'Friday':4,'friday':4,'Saturday':5,'saturday':5,
        'Sunday':6,'sunday':6}

regx = re.compile('((\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d))\s+(%s)' % '|'.join(dico.iterkeys()))



for s in ('2011-08-10  Wednesday', '2011-08-25    Thursday', '2011-08-30  Tuesday',
          '2011-12-04 Sunday', '2011-12-30   Friday',
          '2012-02-18 Saturday', '2012-02-25 Saturday', '2012-02-29   Wednesday ',
          '2011-07-24 sunday', '2011-07-25 monday',
          '2011-10-28 friday', '2011-10-30 monday'):

    print 's == ' + s

    # --- Verifications ----------------------------------------------------------------
    mess = ("The string isn't expressing a date correctly",
            "The date isn't an existing date",
            'The name of week-day in the string is incoherent with the date')   
    try:
        the_date,y,m,d,weekday_name = regx.match(s).groups()    
    except:
        exit(mess[0])
    else:
        try:
            y,m,d = map(int,(y,m,d))
            xdate = date(y,m,d)
        except:
            exit(mess[1])
        else:
            if strptime(the_date,'%Y-%m-%d').tm_wday != dico[weekday_name]:
                exit(mess[2])


    # --- Extraction of the position of the day in the month ----------------------------
    n = (d-1)//7
    # n is in (0,1,2,3,4) , it tells the position of the input day
    # among the list of same week-days in the month


    # --- Going to the first next same week-day in the next month------------------------
    while xdate.month == m:
        xdate = xdate + timedelta(weeks=1)
    # this loop makes xdate to be incremented of one week until reaching the next month


    # --- Displaying the extracted data and the result ----------------------------------
    print '(y,m,d,weekday_name,dico[weekday_name],n) ==',(y,m,d,weekday_name,dico[weekday_name],n)
    print 'The day %s is the %sth %s in the month %s-%s\n' % (d,n+1,weekday_name,y,m)
    # There is no couple of adjacent months in a year having a given week-day name
    # present 5 times (that is to say at position 4) in each of them.
    # Then if n==4, the desired next date can't be xdate + timedelta(weeks=4))
    print 'The %sth %s %s in the next month is on date %s' \
          % (min(n,3)+1,weekday_name,'(the last)' if n==4 else '',xdate + timedelta(weeks=min(n,3)))


    print '\n-------------------------------------------------------------'
```

### Edit 3

Taking account of the remark of *unutbu* that found my code unclear concerning the reason why it is necessary to write `timedelta(weeks=min(n,3))` , I tried to find another algorithm to avoid this min(n,3) instruction.
But I finally realized that no algorithm is able to decide itself what it must do when it is impossible to find the 5th same weekday in the next month. There's no other option for the writer of the code to be the one who realizes this case exists and to decide to take the 4th same weekday instead of the 5th.

So I kept the general principle of my code. But I changed it slightly to make more understandable the use of a **weekday_appear** value instead of the former **n**. I think that the following easily understandable code is the clearer and simpler one that can be written.

```
for s in ('2011-08-10  Wednesday', '2011-08-25 Thursday', '2011-08-30  Tuesday',
          '2011-12-04 Sunday', '2011-12-30   Friday',
          '2012-02-18 Saturday', '2012-02-25 Saturday', '2012-02-29 Wednesday ',
          '2011-07-24 sunday', '2011-07-25 monday',
          '2011-10-28 friday', '2011-10-30 monday'):

    print 's == ' + s

    # --- Verifications --------------------------------------------------------
    mess = ("The string isn't expressing a date correctly",
            "The date isn't an existing date",
            'The name of week-day in the string is incoherent with the date')   
    try:
        the_date,y,m,d,wkd_name = regx.match(s).groups()
        print '(y,m,d,wkd_name) ==',(y,m,d,wkd_name)
    except:
        exit(mess[0])
    else:
        try:
            y,m,d = map(int,(y,m,d))
            xdate = date(y,m,d)
        except:
            exit(mess[1])
        else:
            if xdate.weekday() != dico[wkd_name]:
                exit(mess[2])


    # --- Extraction of the number of the weekday in the month ---------------
    weekday_appear = (d+6)//7
    print 'weekday_appear == %s' % weekday_appear
    # weekday_appear is 1 if 1<=d<=7, 2 if 8<=d<=14 ... 5 if 29<=d<=31
    # It tells if the input weekday is the 1st/2nd/3rd/4th/5th
    # among the list of same weekdays in the month


    # --- Going to the last same weekday in the month-------------------------
    for deltadays in (7,14,21,28):
        try:
            xdate= date(y,m,d+deltadays)
        except:
            break
    # after this loop, xdate is the last date in the month having the same
    # weekday name as input date


    # --- Displaying the result ----------------------------------------------
    # There is no couple of adjacent months in a year in which a given weekday
    # name can be present 5 times in each of the two months .
    # Then, when it happens that wkd_appear==5 in the input month, it is sure
    # that the desired weekday in the next month can't be the 5th one in this
    # month. In the case, we will take the last of the dates with same weekday
    # name in the next month, that is to say the 4th such date.
    # That's the reason of the following reduction:
    next_appear = min(4, weekday_appear)
    # By the way, the fact that every month in a year have a minimum of 4*7
    # days is the reason why it is sure to find at least 4 times in a month
    # any weekday name, whatever which one it is.

    print 'The %sth %s %s in the next month is on date %s' \
          % (next_appear, wkd_name, ('','(the last)')[weekday_appear==5],
             xdate + timedelta(weeks=next_appear))


    print '\n-------------------------------------------------------------'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `WeekOfMonth` offset in Pandas.

Assuming you were starting with the second Wednesday of the first month, or any subsequent day before the second Wednesday of the following month:

```
import pandas as pd

#Create a starting timestamp:
d1 = pd.Timestamp('2011-08-10')

#Add on a WeekOfMonth offset for the second week of month, and the third weekday:
d2 = d1 + pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(week=1,weekday=2)

print(f'{d2:%Y-%m-%d %A}')
>>> 2011-09-14 Wednesday
```

See documentation for pandas.tseries.offsets.WeekOfMonth for more options:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.1/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.WeekOfMonth.html

Answer (score 0):

In case your current date is also second Wednesday than you can use timedelta in this case i guess:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
d = datetime(2011,8,10)
newDate = (d + timedelta(weeks=4))# 4 weeks to next month
if newDate.weekday() == 2 and newDate.day < 8:
    newDate = (d + timedelta(days=1))        
    while newDate.weekday() != 2:
        newDate = (d + timedelta(days=1))
```

Otherwise something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime(2011,8,10)
t = timedelta(days=1)
newDate = d+t

wedCount = 0

while wedCount != 2:
    newDate += t
    if abs(newDate.month-d.month) == 1 and newDate.weekday() == 2:
        wedCount += 1
```

Comment: Your method and example is wrong. It returns 7th of September which is first Wednesday of that month not the second (month starts on Thursday). It would work only in some cases.

Comment: Please give me some cases to check it. I have mentioned that first sample works only when start date is also a second wednesday, while second will work in any case - or i am wrong?

Comment: The case you gave is wrong case. 10th August 2011 (which is second Wednesday of August) + 4 weeks is 7th September 2011 which cannot be second Wednesday since it can occur only on 8th or later.

Comment: Second code sample looks correct, but is not efficient due to loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about second Wednesday in current month you should find 8th day of next month and while current day is not Wednesday add one day.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime                                                                 
from datetime import timedelta                                                  
origDate = datetime.date(2011,8,10)                                              
oneday = timedelta(days=1)                                                      
WEDNESDAY = 2                                                                   
nextMonth = (origDate.month % 12) + 1                                           
newDate = datetime.date(origDate.year, nextMonth, 8)                            
while newDate.weekday() != WEDNESDAY:                                           
    newDate += oneday                                                           
print newDate
```

which gives

```
2011-09-14
```

Last loop can be optimized out by replacing it with:

```
newDate += timedelta(days=(7 + WEDNESDAY - newDate.weekday()) % 7)
```